# Multiple word search in a single table column

Tags: c#, sql

I am create a simple textbox that allow to single word compare into the table.
if i am give multiple keyword into the textbox only one word working on multiple text its not fetch record.
my database table is-

```
id text                                   keyword
1  Somting with keyword1 & Keyword3     keyword1, keyword3
2  Somting with keyword2 & Keyword3     Keyword2, Keyword3
```

Search string is like-
What is Keyword3 with keyword1

Desired result is
Somting with keyword1 & Keyword3 show in record

using c# sql

I am trying

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetChatAutofill]
(
                @term VARCHAR(255)
)
AS
begin  

    select  id ,  text, keyword
        from tbl 
        where keyword in (select keyword from fn_stringSplit(@term) ss where keyword like '%'+SplitValue+'%')

end
```

and for function-

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fn_stringSplit](@StringSplit varchar(max))
returns @table table(SplitValue varchar(10) not null)
as
begin
    Declare @StartVal int
    Declare @endVal int
    set @StringSplit = @StringSplit + ' '
    set @StartVal = 1
    set @endVal = 1
    while @endVal >= 0
        begin
            set  @endVal = charindex(' ',@StringSplit,@StartVal);
            insert into @table select SUBSTRING(@StringSplit,@StartVal,@endVal-1)
            set @StringSplit= SUBSTRING(@StringSplit,@endVal+1, LEN(@StringSplit))
            if @StringSplit = '' set @endVal= -1
        end
    return
end
```

Comment: What is your query? How it'is built using textbox? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

First , Sql Server 2017 has [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Search rows with all requested keywords present procedure.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetChatAutofill]
(
                @term VARCHAR(255)
)
AS
begin  

    select  id,  text, keyword
        from tbl 
        where not exists(
          select 1 
          from STRING_SPLIT(@term, ' ') terms
          where tbl.keyword not like '%'+terms.value+'%')
end
```

Note this may match partial keywords. For example
a call with an argument "key word" will successfully find "keyword1, keyword2" in the table.